# How to pass arguments from c# to python scripts constructor?

Tags: c#, python

I've got a ML script which I wanted to use in my mvc site however I'm wondering how to pass arguments between them such that c# output is the pyhton input/ vice versa

Comment: You could use c# to run an OS command that starts your Python script, then capture the output. Otherwise, make a Python site as well, and pass data over HTTP

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSON- or XML-File.
There you can save your "arguments".